# How to Create PHP Error Logs For Each Subdomains In Apache

Tags: php, apache, iis-7

How to create seperate php error logs for each subdomain. Please consider this question both apache & iis servers.

Comment: In apache you can have a different error log for each virtual host.  If you have mod-php, you can place php errors into the apache error logs. `ErrorLog /var/log/apache/www.foo.com-error.log`.  If you use the same virtual host for multiple subdomains - since apache 2.4 - you can have a custom error log where you could add in the server name.

Answer (score 0):

For apache you can split your log files.

i have done this for a client but check out this post:

[Splitting up Apache Logs for Subdomains](http://freelinuxtutorials.com/quick-tips-and-tricks/splitting-up-apache-logs-for-subdomains/)